# JQuery / Ajax / Async / Different browers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very strange problem with my Ajax in JQuery.
Here is my code. When the servlet works, it adds a user in a dataBase and a div pop with a message.

```
    var aj = $.ajax({
    type:"get",
    //async:false,

    url: "HERE'S THE SERVLET",
    data: {mail : email,login:login,password:password1,nom:nom,prenom:prenom},
    success:function(res){
        alert("success");

    },
    error:function(res){
        console.log(res);
        alert("fail servlet");
    }

  })
  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
          //alert("ok");
            $("#popup").show(800);
            $("#insc").replaceWith(jQuery("#popup"));
        });
  });
```

Here is the problem:

With **Mozilla**, it's all good. The user is added in the dataBase, and I have the #popup div.
With **Chrome**, I don't know why, but the user is added, but the #popup div is not here.
With **IE**, nothing works. The browser doesn't respond, and after a few seconds, the error alert ("fail servlet") comes.

If anyone could help me...
Thanks in advance.

Edit: it works with Chrome, but i still have the problem with IE. (No more async:false, but still the "fail servlet" alert).

Comment: Using `$(document).ready()` in an ajax success handler is almost certainly something not to do. It's not *necessarily* wrong, but it's probably wrong in this case.

Comment: Oh, and your problem may be that you're trying to do a synchronous call, which newer browsers don't like.

Comment: @Pointy Even though I agree about doc.ready, wouldn't it fire immediately upon a successful callback? I thought doc.ready also acted as a promise.

Comment: The error function takes three arguments, the last two of which tell you what the error was, how about you actually look at them?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes probably, but it's just unnecessary.

Comment: I changed somethink in my code, and it worked for Chrome (changed .click() with .submit and it worked). But i still have the problem with IE. The error arguments indicat "error NetworkError".

Comment: Also, i changed my code ( I'll update it). There's no more $(document).ready() in the ajax success handler, and not more async:false. I used.ajaxSuccess()